# What's the Pythonic way to combine two sequences into a dictionary?

Tags: python

Is there a more concise way of doing this in Python?:

```
def toDict(keys, values):
  d = dict()
  for k,v in zip(keys, values):
    d[k] = v

  return d
```

Comment: Along with the correct answers you've had so far for the technique, I'll point out that ‘to_dict’ is more Pythonic than ‘toDict’ when naming a function. See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008 "PEP 8") for the style recommendations for writing Python code.

Comment: +1 for helping someone who is clearly interested 'the way.'

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. However, this would rather belong in a wikified question along the lines of "Python coding style guidelines".

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes:

```
dict(zip(keys,values))
```

Comment: That's pretty compact! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If `keys`' size may be larger then `values`' one then you could use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (Python 2.6) which allows to specify a default value for the rest of the keys:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def to_dict(keys, values, default=None):
    return dict(izip_longest(keys, values, fillvalue=default))
```

Example:

```
>>> to_dict("abcdef", range(3), 10)
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 10, 'd': 10, 'f': 10}
```

NOTE: `itertools.izip*()` functions unlike the `zip()` function return iterators not lists.